# How to show ticks each 1.5 on D3.js?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm learning D3.js to make some graphs and I have issues with the values shown on an axis.

I tried with this:

```js
        var width = 400, height = 400; 
        var svg = d3.select("body") 
            .append("svg") 
            .attr("width", width) 
            .attr("height", height); 
  
        var xscale = d3.scaleLinear() 
            .domain([0.0, 17.0]) 
            .range([0, width]); 

        var x_axis = d3.axisBottom(xscale)
        .tickValues([0.0, 1.5, 3.0, 4.5, 6.0, 7.5, 9.0, 10.5, 12.0, 13.5, 15.0, 16.5]); 
  
        svg.append("g") 
            .attr("transform", `translate(100, ${height - 20})`) 
            .call(x_axis);
```

But It only shows integer ticks.

[result axis](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tdMc.png)

Any help will be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the values are correct on your screen, but the labels of the ticks arent. to fix that add `tickFormat` to override the default labels

```
.tickFormat(t => t)
```